# How to change MinZoomLevel or MaxZoomLevel on MapControl with Bing?

Tags: c#, bing-maps, uwp-maps

So `MinZoomLevel` and `MaxZoomLevel` are get-only properties.

I can't inherit `MapControl` and override them, because `MapControl` is sealed.

I can use different `MapTileSource` and set there `ZoomLevelRange` and that works.

But the main question is, how to set `MinZoomLevel` and `MaxZoomLevel` on default `MapControl` that uses Bing maps? I can't set it on `MapTileSource`of bing maps, because that field is null for bing maps.

Edit: Also with different `MapTileSource` when I set `ZoomLevelRange`, it doesn't help either. You can still scroll outside of it, but you don't get data. So that is just data constriction. Not scroll constriction.

Comment: From the docs for MinZoomLevel: _"The maximum and minimum values of ZoomLevel depend on the type of map view: 2D, 3D, or Streetside"_

Answer (score 0):

MinZoomLevel and MaxZoomLevel are read-only, you can't set them.

Can you try listening to the [ZoomLevelChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.zoomlevelchanged.aspx) and if the zoom level goes outside the range you want to limit it to, set it back within the desired range?

Something like:

```
MapControl mapControl = new MapControl();
mapControl.ZoomLevelChanged += MapControl_ZoomLevelChanged;

private void MapControl_ZoomLevelChanged(MapControl sender, object args)
{
     const int maxZoom = 7;
     const int minZoom = 5;

     if (mapControl.ZoomLevel > maxZoom)
     {
         mapControl.ZoomLevel = maxZoom;
     }
     else if(mapControl.ZoomLevel < minZoom)
     {
         mapControl.ZoomLevel = minZoom;
     }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes I know about that. Thank you. This works, but it is clumsy, because when you scroll with MouseWheel and hit below 5 or above 7 it weirly jumps. Also with different `MapTileSource` when I set `ZoomLevelRange`, it doesn't help either. You can still scroll outside of it, but you don't get data. So that is just data constriction.